# Issues with duplicated Ids in aggregated subquery

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have this query: (apologies for complexity, I'm not certain what I can remove without impacting the question)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total,
SUM(o.total) AS total_loss,
SUM((SELECT SUM(cost_price) FROM `orders_items` WHERE orders_id = o.orders_id)) AS cost_total ,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refunds AS r1 WHERE r1.order_id = r.order_id AND NOT r.reason IS NULL)) AS refund_count ,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exchanges AS e1 WHERE e1.order_id = e.order_id AND e.type = :countResend AND NOT e.reason IS NULL)) AS resend_count ,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exchanges AS e2 WHERE e2.order_id = e.order_id AND e.type = :countExchange AND NOT e.reason IS NULL)) AS exchange_count
FROM orders AS o
JOIN sales_channel_config AS s ON o.sales_channel = s.sales_channel AND o.sub_sales_channel = s.sub_sales_channel
JOIN courier_service AS cs ON o.courier_service = cs.code
LEFT JOIN refunds AS r ON o.orders_id = r.order_id
JOIN orders_items AS oi ON o.orders_id = oi.orders_id
JOIN third_party_config AS tc ON SUBSTRING(oi.product_id_new, 3, 2) = tc.code
LEFT JOIN exchanges AS e ON o.orders_id = e.order_id
WHERE 1 = 1
AND o.tracking_num NOT IN (:cancelStatus)
AND (o.order_date >= :startDate AND o.order_date <= :endDate)
AND o.courier_service = :courier
AND SUBSTRING(oi.product_id_new, 3, 2) = :supplier
AND (NOT r.reason IS NULL OR NOT e.reason IS NULL)
```

The problem I'm having is that the various `SUM((query))` clauses are counting duplicate orders, which is proving difficult to resolve. For example:

```
SUM((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r1.order_id) FROM refunds AS r1 WHERE r1.order_id = r.order_id AND NOT r.reason IS NULL)) AS refund_count ,
```

And

```
SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refunds AS r1 WHERE r1.order_id = r.order_id AND NOT r.reason IS NULL GROUP BY r1.order_id)) AS refund_count ,
```

Do not lower the resulting `SUM` at all. I have confirmed that the data returned will contain duplicates via another structurally identical query that returns rows from the parent query. When the other query is run without duplicate filtering, the counts match correctly so I'm confident that my problem query is accurate aside from including duplicated order ids.

So can anyone suggest another approach I might try?

Comment: Whats the sum you are getting? Isn't it always 1? Where is the outer query group by clause?

Comment: @sagi Grouping on the outer query returns totals per order, effectively the number of times it is duplicated. The sum results I get with my current parameters are exchange_count : 2, refund_count : 41 and resend_count : 3, which is accurate except for including duplicated orders.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might benefit:

I removed most of the select logic and grouped on orders_id, which gives me an entirely accurate list of relevant orders:

```
SELECT o.orders_id AS order_id, r.id AS refund_id, e.id AS exchange_id, e.type AS exchange_type
FROM orders AS o
JOIN sales_channel_config AS s ON o.sales_channel = s.sales_channel AND o.sub_sales_channel = s.sub_sales_channel
JOIN courier_service AS cs ON o.courier_service = cs.code
LEFT JOIN refunds AS r ON o.orders_id = r.order_id
JOIN orders_items AS oi ON o.orders_id = oi.orders_id
JOIN third_party_config AS tc ON SUBSTRING(oi.product_id_new, 3, 2) = tc.code
LEFT JOIN exchanges AS e ON o.orders_id = e.order_id
WHERE 1 = 1
AND o.tracking_num NOT IN (:cancelStatus)
AND (o.order_date >= :startDate
AND o.order_date <= :endDate)
AND o.courier_service = :courier
AND SUBSTRING(oi.product_id_new, 3, 2) = :supplier
AND (NOT r.reason IS NULL OR NOT e.reason IS NULL)
GROUP BY (o.orders_id)
```

I've bitten the bullet here. I'm going to do some post processing to get the counts themselves, which is at least possible for me now.

Still don't understand why getting distinct values in the sub selects failed though.